# How to check if my site is deployed on some server

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, encryption

i want to ask expert advice.

I have a CRM on asp.net  and i am using TS online for development. My developers are using this TFS from office, home and any place. Chances that someone sell this CRM to any other without my notice and deploy this on hosting.

Is there any thing i can do with the code to track the deployment or Hosting address of my sites deployed on any servers. I use google Tracking code but it can be removed easily. OR can i add some encryption code to run website??

Let me know how others are doing this ?

Comment: If you don't trust your developers.... it's a big trouble. Either if you are right or not.
Note that there is nothing you can put in the code to protect you, as long as your developers have access to the code and are able to modify it. Every protection you can add to your code (up to, e.g., check the presence of an hardware key in your customer server), can be removed by developers.
As in every job, you must find people trustworthy for your company.